# Returning pointer to a certain value in a macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a macro that has a type and a value as its input parameters (`MACRO(type,value)`), and returns a valid pointer to a location that holds the submitted `value`.

This macro should perform like the following function, but in a more generic manner:

```
int *val_to_ptr(int val){
    int *r = NULL;
    r = nm_malloc(sizeof(*r));
    *r = val;
    return r;
}
```

Where `nm_malloc()` is a failsafe malloc.
The Macro usage should be compatible with this usage:

```
printf("%d",*MACRO(int,5));
```

Is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: So you want a macro that allocates some type T, initializes it, and returns a pointer to it? Why not use a template function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation which is modelled on c++ templates

```
#define DEFINE_TEMPLATE(type) \
type * val_to_ptr_##type(type val){\
    type * ptr = NULL;\
    ptr = nm_malloc(sizeof(*ptr));\
    *ptr = val;\
    return ptr;\
}

#define USE_TEMPLATE(type,val)\
val_to_ptr_##type(val)

DEFINE_TEMPLATE(int);
int main(){
    printf("%d",*USE_TEMPLATE(int,5));
    return 0;
}
```

You'd have to explicitly define what types you're using it for, and would have to typedef things like `unsigned int` or `double complex` or the token paste won't work.

Alternately use

```
USE_TEMPLATE(type) val_to_ptr_##type
```

and call

```
USE_TEMPLATE(int)(5);
```

without having to worry about argument evaluation

Comment: Is there any way to prevent multiple instantiation of the same function ?

Comment: @Andrei you might be able to declare the function `inline`, i.e. `inline type * val_to_ptr_##type` in the `DEFINE_TEMPLATE` macro. I think that would still be an error if you defined it for the same type more than once in the same file though.

Comment: Alternately if you want to get really complicated create a macro `#define DECLARE_TEMPLATE(type) type* val_to_ptr_##type(type val)`
which you could use multiple times for the same type, and ensure you link in a file which has `DEFINE_TEMPLATE` used for that type.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using gcc, you can use [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs):

```
#define MACRO(type,value) ({ type* t = nm_malloc(sizeof(*t)); *t = (value); t; })
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps (untested):

```
#define ALLOC_AND_INIT(T, val) *(T*)malloc(sizeof(T))=(val)
```

Usage

```
printf("%d\n", ALLOC_AND_INIT(int, 5));  // memory leak :)
```

Comment: printf("%d\n", *ALLOC_AND_INIT(int,5)); - This was the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the solutions using `malloc()` will cause a memory leak in the example you gave.  However, this simple solution, using C99 compound literals, does not:

```
#define MACRO(type, val) (&(type){val})
```